# Questions about Java replace String

Tags: java

I want to use regular expressions or other methods to replace:

```
<image id='123123123213' name='1&2.png' src='http://image.com/image&123213' />
```

name = '1&2.png' to name = '1-2.png'  But not affect the & in src, how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

This will help you,

```
<image id='123123123213' name='1&#8212;2.png' src='http://image.com/image&123213' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 String s = "<image id='123123123213' name='1&2.png' src='http://image.com/image&123213' />";
 String t = s.replace("1&2", "1-2");
```

Comment: He probably wants to replace all `&` chars in *name* by '-', and not exactly `1&2`.

Comment: He wrote "But not affect the & in src"

Comment: Replacing the & in `<image id='foo name='foo&bar.png' src='http://image.com/foo&bar />` should result in `<image id='foo name='foo-bar.png' src='http://image.com/foo&bar />`, as far as I understand him. And by name I did not mean the whole string, but the `name='<stuff>'` area.